# SQL injection id name contains '&'

Tags: php, html, sql-server

in my php code i am passing an id for the php to get the info from the sql server.
it seems to work fine but whenever i have an '&' in the name, it doesn't work any more

```
$doc_info = array();
$id = "ID not set";
if(isset($_GET['document_id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['document_id'];
    $id = str_replace('___', '&', $id);
    $doc_info = get_document_info($id);
    $doc_info['dummy'] = "&nbsp;";
}
```

example of an id that works "2017_test id"

```
http://localhost/php/single-entry.php?document_id=2017_test%20id
```

here I get the info right.

example of an id that doesn't work "2017_e&i EDV"

```
http://localhost/php/single-entry.php?document_id=2017_e&i%20EDV
```

here I get  PHP WARNING:  **Undefined index**. although the data is in DB.

I am passing the id to another function that get an array of the info stored in the DB with this ID . 
in first example I get the data, but if the name has '&' i get  **Undefined index**

Comment: What does "does not work" exactly mean?

Comment: Learn about url encoding, because certain characters like `?`, `=` and `&` have a special meaning in URLs as GET argument separators

Comment: The & in the $_GET is a special character. Convert from G_GET to $_POST and see if that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

> urlencode($document_id) - while sending the request to your php script
>   And as pointed on in comment section, $_GET["document_id"] would give
>   you already decoded value

And use the decoded value instead in your PHP script.

Comment: You don't need to `urldecode`, it's done automatically.

Comment: Nope, `urldecode($_GET["document_id"])` is totally redundant (and potentially harmful).

Comment: @zerkms why is it harmful, explain please.

Comment: Well even if it is redundant but it didn't work anyways.

Comment: @Tarun because it mutates the user's original data